# I want to change my post titles from h2 to H1

Tags: css

Currently my current blog CSS has the post titles formatted to be an H2, I want them to be the H1 of the page.

How would I find that in my CSS to make the update?

Or how would you recommend I resolve this?

This is an example of one post, but I would like this to be a global change for all posts.

https://www.lookaboutlindsey.com/why-taylors-falls-mn-is-the-ultimate-fall-day-trip/

Answer (score 2):

IT's best to change the template used, rather than overwriting CSS.

Make a Child Theme, then copy the single.php into your Child Theme folder. Modify the copied single.php to change the H1 tag to H2.

Using a Child Theme ensures that your customizations aren't overwritten with a theme update.

Answer (score 1):

There are different solutions against your purpose.

If you want to your title looks like `h1` then you can solve it by `css` (like: overwriting `h1` property into `h2.title`).

But if your purpose is for SEO then css solution won't work, you need to replace the `h2` tag with `h1` and for that you have to edit your current theme and find `<h2 class="title">` in `single.php` or `content.php` or any other file (depending on your theme), then change `h2` to `h1` and that's it.

So, take your decision.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is for SEO. Where do I go in and edit my current theme in single.php or content.php? I have the Amory theme, the theme options are pretty basic and not sure where I would go to make these updates.

Comment: In that case child theme creation is right solution, which @rick-hellewell answered.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. But if you are doing it solely for SEO, be aware that the H!/H2 tags are not as important to the googles anymore.